# Can we create a static message using TwiMLBin for SMS to use as messaging Fallback URL?

Tags: twilio

In case my Web Service is not up and running for handling the incoming text messages. So in such cases can I create a static message using TwiMLBin for SMS to use as messaging Fallback URL? Anybody have used this and do you know if this is part of the Twilio account? Or do you know any other way that we can create a Static message to be sent for fallback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here. You can put the static TwiML file anywhere you like. Amazon's S3 is quite a good idea. But you can use TwiMLBin, DropBox, or anything that can serve a static file correctly. But I'd suggest you look into how that file is hosted, and how reliable it is likely to be as compared to your web hook.

Comment: I would prefer something that Twilio offers. I tried to create one using Twimlet echo but looks like it is only applicable for calls and not for messages. Is there something that I can use that Twilio offers?

Comment: I'm afraid Twilio doesn't have anything that can host your TwiML. We generally point people towards TwiMLBin etc. If we can offer anything more, feel free to shoot an email to help at twilio dot com.

Comment: I was able to use Twimlet Echo from: https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/echo to create a static message for now as Fallback message.